# How to get SSL certification for svn server in android

Tags: android-studio, svn, svn-repository

Am new to android i want to checkout project from svn repo to my android studio whenever am trying to do its showing an stating that "Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a different hostname, issuer is not trusted"

Below is the screen shot of error message please look into it and let me know the issue.

[image: svn_error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is

> Server SSL certificate verification failed: certificate issued for a
>   different hostname, issuer is not trusted

Use the correct FQDN or hostname in the URL or request an admin to fix the error with the certificate. The certificate was issued to a different name than you use in the URL.

Comment: sure thanks for the suggestion!!! let me fix that first with admin if it works !!... i will upmark..